# Linux - System has no HDD's or root mount

Tags: linux

I must be missing something... anyone have any idea how this system is even functioning?
Please tell me im dreaming...

Ive lost access to many files i had stored in /var/ just dissapered...

Ubuntu on openvz

```
root@telesto:/# mount -l
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw)
varrun on /var/run type tmpfs (rw)
varlock on /var/lock type tmpfs (rw)
root@telesto:/# df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
varrun                 4093136        44   4093092   1% /var/run
varlock                4093136         0   4093136   0% /var/lock
root@telesto:/# ls /dev | grep sd
root@telesto:/# ls /dev | grep hd
root@telesto:/# dmesg
root@telesto:/# dmesg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's functioning because a lot of the necessary stuff is loaded into memory.  But it likely won't be for long.

If you can find out where the various partitions are, such as from `cat /etc/fstab` you might be able to run fsck on them and maybe remount them.  But if you don't you're going to need to boot this off of some other media (like a DVD of your OS) and do a recovery.  Really, if `dmesg` isn't returning anything, you are probably already at that state.